# Linux L2TP Daemon Recommendation

Tags: linux, l2tp

I need to setup a tunnel between two points with no encryption.  I know this is generally done using L2TP but what would be the recommended daemon to use.  I know of rp-l2tp which I have used in the past successfully but was wondering if there was anything else which may be considered a better choice?

Answer (score 3):

My tool of choice for VPN tunnels on Linux has been OpenVPN, as of late.

I don't know if you want only layer 3 functionality or if you'd like layer 2 (forwarding broadcasts, etc) functionality as well. [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) will do both under Linux (with the "tun" and "tap" drivers, respectively) and can be configured for no authentication or encryption (though I'd recommend at using authentication even if you're not going to use encryption). The "cipher none" command can be substituted into most tutorial and "recipe" OpenVPN configurations to get you no encryption on the tunnel.

Comment: I agree OpenVPN is also my tool of choice.  Sorry was not clear enough as this the VPN endpoint is to be an ADSL router and they tend to not support OpenVPN so that unfortunately causes a problem for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the phrase "they tend to not support OpenVPN". If you're implying that you're wanting to run OpenVPN on the router itself have a look at routers that can run the OpenWRT firmware stack. There are plenty of them, and OpenVPN runs great on OpenWRT.